# Searching a file and returning value - Super Fast

Tags: c, search

I have a set of data which has a name, some sub values and then a associative numeric value. For example:

```
James Value1 Value2 "1.232323/1.232334"
Jim   Value1 Value2 "1.245454/1.232999"
Dave  Value1 Value2 "1.267623/1.277777"
```

There will be around 100,000 entries like this stored in either a file or database. I would like to know, what is the quickest way of being able to return the results which match a search, along with their associated numeric value.

For example, a query of "J" would return both James and Jim results which the numeric values in the last column.

I've heard people mention binary tree searching, dictionary searching, indexed searching. I have no idea which is a good route to peruse.

Comment: what would the query `im` return? and `1.23`? Please describe what kind of searches do you want to perform...

Comment: You'll probably need to specify a little more information, because the recommended data structures and algorithms can vary depending on expected use. For example, do you only search on the value of the first field, or possibly on others. Are the searches always prefixes, or would e.g. searching for 'A' find James and Dave?

Comment: Thank you both for the reply. The query "im" would return no results, the same as if someone searched for "ave" they would get no results, but search for "Dav" and it would find "Dave".

Comment: balanced binary search tree should be fine for that

Answer (score 1):

This is a poorly characterized problem. As with many optimization problems, there are trade-offs in resources. If you truly want the fastest response possible, then a likely approach is to compile all possible searches into a table of prepared results, so that, given a search key, you can look the search key up in the table and return the result.

Assuming your character set is limited to A-Z and a-z, a table with an entry for each search key from 0 to 4 characters will use a modest amount of memory by today’s standards. Each table entry merely needs to have two values in it: The start and end positions in a list of the numeric values. (Compile the list in this way: Sort the records by the name field. Extract just the numeric values from the records, maintaining the order, putting them in a list. Any search key must return a sublist of contiguous records from that list. This is because the search is for a prefix string of the name field, so any records that match the search key are adjacent, when sorted by the name field.)

Thus, to create a table to look up any key of 0 to 4 characters, you need fewer than 53<sup>4</sup> entries in a table of pairs, where each member of the pair contains a record number (32 bits or fewer). So 8•534 = 60.2 MiB suffices. (53 is because you have 52 characters plus one sentinel character to mark the end of the key. Alternate encodings could reduce this some.)

To support keys of more than 4 characters, you need to extend this. With typical data, 4 characters will have narrowed down the search greatly, so you can take the set of records indicated by the first 4 characters and prune it to get the final results. If the data has pathological cases where 4 characters does not reduce the search much, you can embellish this technique.

So, is that really what you want to do, make the speed as fast as possible, regardless of other resources (including engineering time) consumed? If not, what are your actual goals?

Comment: The lookup table in itself is not large, but the whole data structure could be (with all the results for short 1 and 2 character prefixes). With just 100k entry in a compact BST (2M?) you might have something which is modern processor cache-friendly, and perform better... but just an idea, you newer know till you measure it...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: The **entire** structure for 0 to 4 byte keys is 53**4 table entries of eight bytes each plus one table of the 100,000 numeric pairs. If they are in the form shown in the question, they are 20 bytes each (including digits, periods, slash, and a terminator). So the total memory is 62.1 MiB. And a lookup is just some arithmetic to convert an ASCII key into table index, then one or two memory loads to get the eight bytes from the table. Those can be used to calculate an address and a length to return as the search results. No binary search tree will beat that.

Comment: 1) "entries of eight bytes each" - I was referring to this.. I guess that is a pointer, but where is it pointing to? You have a whole list of results for that key. 2) never underestimate the costs of a cache miss.

Comment: Each table entry is two numbers. The first number is the number of the first record in the sorted table that matches. The second number is the number of the last record in the sorted table that matches (or, equivalently, the number one beyond the last matching record or the number of matching records). That is it. If the numbers are 10 and 20, then you return to the caller the address of the 10th pair in the second table and the length of 11 entries. That gives the caller a list of 11 pairs of numbers, found at the address you returned, and those are the search results.

Comment: There is at most one cache miss in this table lookup method: The load of the table entry. That is it. There is no other data lookup (for keys fitting within the 4 byte limit). No binary search tree can beat that because no other data structure of any kind can beat one cache miss. (Well, there is one exception: You fit **all** of the data into cache, so you can do lookups without any cache misses and faster than a cache miss.)

Comment: sorry, I missed that part, now I get the 8 bytes. regarding to the other part, 0 misses clearly beats it (that's why I said your whole data set could fit in the cache). now, depending on the size of the app that might not a realistic presumption.